# XAMPP on Mac OSX - Really slow page loads

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, xampp

I've recently been developing a Laravel app on my Mac OSX under an XAMPP/Apache server. And suddenly a couple days ago (no updates or anything) my server started resolving the pages at over a minute (roughly 80s on average). It obviously makes development really difficult and was wondering the possible issues could be? Please let me know what files/code snippets would be needed!

I'm running my app on a virtual host in the httpd.conf file if that's any help. 
I've also reinstalled XAMPP with PHP 7.0 and reset my entire repo as well but to no avail. Other website load perfectly fine too. Other coders on the app don't see a change in the loading time, so this seems like a local issue and not one concerning the size of the app.

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: May be its an issue with laravel, delete cache and run composer update and update your project dependencues to latest version

Comment: It could be a DNS problem. Check the configuration

Comment: @Stacklearner, I don't think it's a laravel issue. I've done a lot of composer updates and cache clearing too, maybe it is, but I don't know how else to optimize it (did all the artisan commands that would optimize it).

Comment: @JesúsAmieiro What configuration should I check? My network settings have always remained default on my Mac, what would I need to do to fix/check my DNS config?

Comment: Are you sure there is no leak in the code? May be you left some stray piece of code use a profiler like black fire and check your code, and check the execution times of the scripts

Comment: @Stacklearner I don't think it's the laravel side only because my co worker doesn't have any lag time in his load! His works pretty smoothly. I'm thinking maybe it's on the angularjs side or the DNS configurations, I just don't know where to look!